# HTML5 video and caption sync with css animations

Tags: html, html5-video, caption

I'm trying to make a html5 video(around a minute long) and I want to put some synchronized text above it and use CSS animation to manipulate it... Basically I know how to do all that, except of the sync part... How do I actually can sync caption from specific time/frame to some other specific time/frame of the video, but with the ability to manipulate the caption with CSS?

Comment: I am not a web developer, but from other front end development, I would assume this is far easier to accomplish using premiere pro or other video editing software.

Comment: @Sethmr that's obvious, pal :) It's a bit different story, not related to the subject.